# ubuntu : Schedule python scripts using Fork

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cron, fork

I am trying to use `fork()` in Ubuntu 16.04 to execute a python script at some scheduled time. As I read through the docs, I did not come across the scheduling option in `fork()`.

> Is fork() having an option to schedule?

Presently, I am using `CRON' to call the python scripts but it seems like CRON jobs are always having a least priority.

> What would be the best possible option to schedule daily ops in Ubuntu which performs huge DB operations?

Answer (score 0):

Advanced Python Scheduler can help: http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Here is a sample code for using it:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

def some_job():
    print "Decorated job"

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(some_job, 'interval', hours=1) 
scheduler.start()
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Do you have any info regarding the `fork`. Is it having any scheduling functionality